# Why did Mike Wazowski get banned from Monster University?

Tags: plot-explanation, monsters-university

Mike Wazowski gest banned from the Monsers University because he gets to the human world without approval and uses scare tactics on adults.

But watching the scene, I realized how much scream he could actually generate. And later on he is asked how the heck he was able to do it.

But still, he gets banned from the school. I cannot understand why. If he stayed, the monsters could produce much more scream than just by scaring children.

Is there any (in-universe or out-of-universe) explanation for this?

Comment: Because children tend not to be able to kill monsters.

Comment: @cde but Monsters believe they are able to...

Comment: Key word "believe". Children just don't have the physical strength, or you know, guns and centuries of learning how to kill others.

Comment: @Well, if I believe that sheeps and spiders kill, I will approach them the same way even if the spiders can actually kill me (well at least with bigger probability than getting killed by sheep)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, he produced a lot of scream - but he almost nearly revealed the existence of monsters to humanity. We know from both *Monsters University* and *Monsters Inc* that this is one of the worst things a monster can do.

Just like in real life, your grades don't matter if you do something worthy of being expelled, and in this case Mike did one of the worst things a monster can do.